# SQL Server Woocommerce API connection gives NULL when getting products, works fine with orders

Tags: sql-server, api, woocommerce

I am trying to set up a connection between a external SQL Server Database and the Woocommerce API.

The goal is to communicate between 2 websites, where they exchange data, the external website will send a POST request to Woocommerce to create a product, then GET the list of products to select the latest added one and then uses that product ID to create a add to cart link which will put the product into the Cart.

Now here is my code :

```
    DECLARE @contentType NVARCHAR(64);
    DECLARE @ret INT;
    DECLARE @responseText NVARCHAR(4000);
    DECLARE @status NVARCHAR(32);
    DECLARE @statusText NVARCHAR(32);
    DECLARE @token INT;
    DECLARE @url NVARCHAR(256);

    SET @contentType = 'application/json';

    set @url = 'https://mywebsite.com/wp-json/wc/v3/products/?consumer_key=mykey&oauth_signature_method=HMAC-SHA1&oauth_timestamp=1458225139&oauth_nonce=nVq4rX&consumer_secret=mysecret&oauth_signature=kzoVx%20VYSWlLbRpi3f8222222%3D'


    EXEC @ret = sp_OACreate 'WinHttp.WinHttpRequest.5.1', @token OUT;

    EXEC @ret = sp_OAMethod @token, 'open', NULL, 'GET', @url, 'false';
    EXEC @ret = sp_OAMethod @token, 'setRequestHeader', NULL, 'Content-type', @contentType;
    EXEC @ret = sp_OAMethod @token, 'send', NULL;

    EXEC @ret = sp_OAGetProperty @token, 'status', @status OUT;
    EXEC @ret = sp_OAGetProperty @token, 'statusText', @statusText OUT;
    EXEC @ret = sp_OAGetProperty @token, 'responseText', @responseText OUT;

    EXEC @ret = sp_OADestroy @token;

    RETURN @responseText;
```

When i return the status i get 200, which to my knowledge is the desirable status.

But when i return responseText i get null.

The infuriating part is when i replace products with orders i get a result as expected, but when getting the products it keeps saying NULL.

Please help, because i am losing the last few hairs on my head.

Also my boss insists on doing it by SQL Server..